# Etendue of the eye

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

I am tasked with calculating the Etendue of an eye with the given values:

diameter of the pupil = 4 mm

diameter of the retina (the active area) = 6 mm

distance from the lens to the retina (b) = 20 mm

[image]

I am assuming that the projected area before the lens is $\Delta$A = $\pi r_{pupil}^{2}$ since the pupil is circular. I am struggling the most with the solid angle $\Delta \Omega$. My thought was that the solid angle is then $\Delta \Omega$ = $\frac{\pi d^{2}}{b^{2}}$ with d being the diameter of the retina and b being the distance between the lens and the retina.

If I am solving for the etendue of the eye, is that then the etendue at the image? So would the projected area and the solid angle be necessarily changed?

I do not have the pupil to lens distance.

Comment: What is the meaning of *etendue* ?

Comment: Etendue characterizes the spread of light based on angle and area. The equation is defined as follows: $\Delta G = \Delta A * \Delta \Omega$

Comment: with google you find many good explanations   for example https://www.db-thueringen.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/dbt_derivate_00039270/ilm1-2017iwk-141.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue